# Use Linq to get the last order placed yesterday for each customer

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following two POCO's

```
public class Customers
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Orders
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming my Data Service returns a List<Customers> and List<Orders>, how would I use Linq to get the last order placed yesterday for each customer?

I want to return Customer.Id, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Order.Id, Order.Date and Order.Product (as Json from a controller action), so would I need to also create a new POCO to hold results? something like the following:

```
public class CustomerOrders
{
    public Guid CustomerId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public Guid OrderId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public string Product {get;set;}
}
```

I previously posted a similar question on using Linq to work with lists. I'm still learning Linq and these questions have me somewhat stumped. I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var results = customers
    .Select(c =>
        orders
            .Where(o => o.CustomerId == c.Id)
            .Where(o => o.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
            .Select(o => new CustomerOrders()
            {
                Product = o.Product,
                Date = o.Date,
                CustomerId = c.Id,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                OrderId = o.Id
            })
            .First())
    .ToList();
```

Here is another version that handles the case where the customer does not have a corresponding order that meets the criteria:

```
var results = customers
    .Select(c =>
        orders
            .Where(o => o.CustomerId == c.Id)
            .Where(o => o.Date.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Select(o => new CustomerOrders()
            {
                Product = o == null ? default(string) : o.Product,
                Date = o == null ? default(DateTime) : o.Date,
                CustomerId = c.Id,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                OrderId = o == null ? default(Guid) : o.Id
            })
            .First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting an InvalidOperationException with highlighting on the inner orders...First().

Comment: Maybe some customer does not have a corresponding order? how do you want to handle such case?

Comment: That was the problem. One of the customers did not have an order yesterday. To handle this case, I just adjusted the data. That's all I need for this example.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how could I handle this situation (with no data for yesterday) and just default to an empty record for any user without a visit yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

Probably Something like..

```
var res = from c in customers
          join o in orders on c.Id equals o.CustomerId
          where o.Id == (orders.Where(x=>x.CustomerId == o.CustomerId).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)).First().Id
          && DateTime.Compare(o.Date, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) > 0
          select new CustomerOrders {
              CustomerId = c.Id, FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName,
              OrderId = o.Id, Date = o.Date, Product = o.Product 
          };
```

P.S. I wrote it without compiling, you might get some errors, but I guess you got the point.

Comment: This won't compile, but looks like what I'm trying to do. I am having problems inside the where clause: orders.where(x=>x... it says that there is an invalid expression term 'where'.

Comment: Could you specify what is the problem with this implementation ?

Comment: The problem with this entry has to do with the following line:

where o.Id == (orders.where(x=>x.CustomerId == o.CustomerId).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)).First().Id

the inner orders.where shows an error compiling that 'where' is an invalid epression. As a result First() does not exist in the current context, as well as the select

Comment: You know that 'Orders' is List<Orders> with data in it right?

Comment: there is definitely data in the list. The errors are not at runtime, but at design time and won't compile.

Comment: That was the problem. So easy. Thanks for helping me find the problem. It was an issue because 'where' with a lowercase was still colored and caused some confusion. This now works.